# Why is my object rendering so bright?

Tags: light, lighting

I have played with different lighting options, turned the power down to 50W and placed the light far from the object and it still renders bright even when ambient occlusion is turned off.

I have no idea why.

I have attached an image below
[image]

[image]

Comment: Light.001 is hidden in viewport, but that doesn't hide it in the render.  Where is it located?

Comment: Bring the intensity down even more. Check that the color of the world is not to bright.

Comment: Even when my Watt is set to 0, the render is still bright white. My background color in world is set to a V of 250 as well which is standard

Comment: have you checked the render visibility of light.001 as suggested by  Allen Simpson? You need to go in the Outliner, click on the funnel icon and display the Disable in Renders options, then check if it's not enabled for this light

Comment: I added that extra light to see if that would make a difference, but it didn't that's why it's hidden. My render is coming out too bright, so wouldn't an extra light just make it worse?